# Issue recovering Touch Events with multi-touch screen

Tags: c#, touch, multi-touch

I recently received a brand new Acer T232HL multi-touch screen at my work to be able to debug a multi touch application. The multi touch function is working great in Paint or with sample application.

However when I try it on my own applications programmed in C# I have issues and no touch events are launched. I tried two samples (from the MSDN website):

- A simple scatter view application without touch events handling
- A scatter view application with touch events handling

I used a tool called Snoop to see which events my application can detect. None of my application can detect `TouchDown`, `TouchMove` or `TouchUp` events. I guess any touch events cannot be detected by my application except the virtual keyboard key events.

I looked at the control panel for "Pen and touch settings" but I cannot see anything wrong with it.

Does anyone had this problem before? How could I set my screen to be listened by my C# programs?